# How can I merge two mysql databases with identical schema?

Tags: mysql, database, merge, foreign-key-relationship

I need to merge two two mysql databases with identical schema. I am looking for some tool that can read database meta-data (PK, FK) and automatically generate new PKs, updating all the FKs automatically.

Comment: I also need to do this, except I need to merge about 6 MySQL databases with identical schema, maintaining foreign key relationships.

Comment: I think once we have a way to do it for two databases, doing it for 6 databases will just requiring repeating the process five times

Answer (score 3):

Check out SqlYog - http://www.webyog.com/en/.  There is a 30 day trial for the enterprise edition which includes a tool to synchtonise data between databases (among many other useful tools).

Comment: NOTE: They only allow two database tables at a time in the trial version.

Answer (score 0):

for every table:

```
insert into `target db`.`table`
(`all`,`clumns`,`except`,`pk`) 

select (`all`,`clumns`,`except`,`pk`) form `source db`.`table`;
```

you can generate this with php or even in sql
don't forget `information_schema`.`columns`

```
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `COLUMN_KEY` <> 'PRI' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='source db'
```

now you have all column names without the pk's

Comment: So far so good, but we will need to update the FKs as well

Answer (score -2):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but if you got two databases and want to make them identifcal,try this tool - [Database compare](http://nobhillsoft.com/NHDBCompare.aspx)

Comment: It seems that his databases are already identical, and he just wants to combine the data in them.